# In MediaWiki, why no caption in images if positioned left? As designed, or ...?

Tags: mediawiki

In my wiki, if I set the image

```
[[File:StackOverflowProvilePic.jpeg‎|left|Yes, this is me]]
```

then the image displays on the left with text flow around it all right, but the caption is missing -- although it does display as an Alt.

Meanwhile, this

```
[[File:StackOverflowProvilePic.jpeg‎|thumb|Yes, this is me]]
```

causes the image to thumbnail, and then the caption appears.  I can make the image appear on the left and the caption appear if I do this

```
[[File:StackOverflowProvilePic.jpeg‎|left|thumb|Yes, this is me]]
```

But I don't want to thumbnail the image!  How do I make this work with a caption without thumbnailing it?

Answer (score 4):

OK, I figured it out.

I have done this and it works the way I want:

```
[[File:StackOverflowProvilePic.jpeg‎|left|frame|Yes, this is me]]
```

Apparently you can add many options between the image filename and the caption text.  Why leaving that frame or thumb option off would cause the caption text to not appear is a mystery.  To me, anyway.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer, otherwise the question will still appear as unanswered. Thanks!